# Fill arrays with ranges of numbers

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any syntax/package allowing quick filling of java arrays with ranges of numbers, like in perl?

e.g.

```
int[] arr = new int[1000];
arr=(1..500,301..400,1001..1400); // returns [1,2,3,4,...,500,301,302,...,400,1001,1002,...1400]
```

Also, it here a package that allows getting the n-th number in such list of numbers as the above, without actually creating the array (which can be huge)?

e.g.

```
BunchOfRangesType bort = new BunchOfRangesType("1..500","301..400","1001..1400");
bort.get(0); // return 1
bort.get(500); // return 301
bort.get(501); // return 302
```

It's not too difficult to implement, but I guess it might be common so maybe it was already done.

Comment: Or just use Groovy ;-) `def arr = (1..500)+(301..400)+(1001..1400)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite as clean as True Soft's answer, but you can use [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to the same effect:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //one liner
        int[] array = toArray(newLinkedList(concat(range(1, 10), range(500, 1000))));

        //more readable
        Iterable<Integer> values = concat(range(1, 10), range(500, 1000));
        List<Integer> list = newLinkedList(values);
        int[] array = toArray(list);

    }

    public static List<Integer> range(int min, int max) {
        List<Integer> list = newLinkedList();
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        return list;
    }

}
```

Note you need a few static imports for this to work.

Comment: Even if more verbose, that's much much clearer than the dollar approach.

Comment: I don't think static imports are very clean.  I would prefer a custom implementation than to do this.

Comment: @Erick "I don't think static imports are very clean." You can of course use the fully qualified method names, however using the static imports does make the code less verbose.

Comment: Verbosity can improve readability, which is desired.  I always reference the class name when calling static methods.  I want to make it as easy as possible for the next programmer to understand.  I don't see a benefit to making the code less verbose, or compact enough to fit in one line.  These things do nothing to improve performance, and only obfuscate the code.

Comment: "Note you need a few static imports for this to work"

it would have been helpfull to include them in your code.

range(...) can be found in com.google.common.collect.Range
toArray(Range<T>) can be found in com.google.common.collect.Iterables
newLinkedList(..) can be found in com.google.common.collect.Lists

Answer (score 145):

For those still looking for a solution:

In Java 8 or later, this can be answered trivially using Streams without any loops or additional libraries.

```
int[] range = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).toArray();
```

This will produce an array with the integers from 1 to 10.

A more general solution that produces the same result is below.  This can be made to produce any sequence by modifying the unary operator.

```
int[] range = IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1).limit(10).toArray();
```

Comment: in JDK-9 the last variant can be `int[] range = IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n <= 10, n -> n + 1).toArray();`.

Comment: for those (like me) who want to have the resulting range in a List you can use
the `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`
(credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674624/how-do-i-convert-a-java-8-intstream-to-a-list)

Comment: `IntStream` is available for API LEVEL 24+ (Android Studio). What solution as simple as that do we have for API LEVEL below 24?

Answer (score 18):

There is [dollar](https://bitbucket.org/adamldavis/dollar/wiki/Home):

```
// build the List 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
List<Integer> list2 = $(10, 15).toList();
```

maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bitbucket.dollar</groupId>
        <artifactId>dollar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can't find anything like this either.  This  is only valid in Java if you define the $ method yourself.

Comment: After further review, it appears that "dollar" is a library which defines the $ method as a static method of a Dollar class.  With the link dead, it's nearly impossible to actually find the code to this.  So this answer is pretty useless.  Full java syntax would require calling this as Dollar.$(10, 15).toList().

Comment: @Erick, yes, `$` is a method. What do you mean by *'the link dead'*? The source code for this library is available, too.

Comment: @Erick - not if you `import static com.humaorie.dollar.Dollar.*`.

Comment: @True Soft: The bitbucket.org link is dead.  So currently, nothing is available.  @Andrzej: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.  At issue is code clarity.  No performance is gained by doing that, just code obfuscation.

Comment: The link is ok. I mean, if I click on the link in my answer, I go to that page.

Comment: @AikoV3, maybe they removed it from BitBucket. A blog post about this is http://adamldavis.com/post/26847919076/dollar-java-api-that-unifies-collections-arrays

Comment: So, we want to use a package for creating a range-array?

Answer (score 18):

Another useful and not widely known Java 8 solution for existing arrays:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
Arrays.setAll(array, i -> i + 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

As for the first question, whether it is possible to fill an array with the values of a range: it is actually possible to achieve that with the combination of [Range](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html), [DiscreteDomain](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/DiscreteDomain.html), [ContiguousSet](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ContiguousSet.html) and [Ints](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
int[] array = Ints.toArray(
    ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(1, 500), DiscreteDomain.integers()));
```

And, not exactly what is mentioned in the second part of the question, but it is possible to create a set with the elements of a range of a discrete domain:

```
Set<Integer> numbersFrom1To500 = 
    ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(1, 500), DiscreteDomain.integers());
```

The resulting `Set` will not contain the specified elements physically, only logically (so it's memory footprint will be small), but can be iterated (since it's a `Set`):

```
for (Integer integer : numbersFrom1To500) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    List<Integer> arrayOfRange  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] range = IntStream.iterate(1, n -> {arrayOfRange.add(n);return n + 1;}).limit(10).toArray();
```

// in addition to what craig answer if you want to have Integer
 2nd approch

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(range).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int[] getRangeArray(int start, int end){
        final int[] rangeArray = new int[end-start + 1];
            for(int i = 0; i < rangeArray.length; i++){
                rangeArray[i] = start + i;
          }
       return rangeArray; // It includes start and end values as well, pls adjust according to your need
  }
```