# shortest way of filling an array with 1,2...n

Tags: java, arrays

Is there anything as quick as this in java? ( quick in coding)

```
int [] a = {1..99};
```

or I have to go for this:

```
int [] a=new int[100];
for (int i=0;i <100;++i){
a[i]=i;
}
```

Comment: You have to loop I'm afraid...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128737/fastest-way-to-set-all-values-of-an-array

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790142/java-equivalent-of-pythons-rangeint-int

Comment: Java 8 will have a lazy sequence for 1..99 and a functional fill. Not necessarily more efficient, but possibly.

Comment: Quick in computing time or coding ?

Comment: @Arnaldo Gaspar , quick in coding I meant.

Comment: You can drop the `{` and `}` It's not something you need to do in Java very often so I can't imagine this being added as a feature soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill arrays with ranges of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387373/fill-arrays-with-ranges-of-numbers)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I have tested the performance of two versions of that method - one with a loop and the other one using guava:

```
public int[] loop() {
    int[] a = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    return a;
}

public int[] guava() {
    Set<Integer> set = ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(0, 99), DiscreteDomains.integers());
    int[] a = Ints.toArray(set);
    return a;
}
```

Here are the results:

```
Benchmark     Mean     Mean error          Var    Units
loop        79.913          5.671       30.447  nsec/op
guava      814.753         46.359     2034.726  nsec/op
```

So the `guava()` method runs in 814 ns +/- 46ns vs. 80 ns +/- 5ns for the `loop()` method. So `loop()` is about 10x faster. If you call that method a few times, the 800 nanoseconds don't matter, if you call it very often, writing the loop is probably better.

Answer (score 122):

Since **Java 8** this is possible:

```
int[] a = IntStream.range(1, 100).toArray();
```

(And shorter than the other java 8 answer .).

Comment: Arrays.setAll() is a much better way.

Comment: @Arkadiy might be a matter of taste but IMHO using `IntStream#toArray` is much better to read than `Arrays#setAll`.

Comment: Is there any way to create an array of User-defined classes? in same fashion we have created `int[] a`

Comment: The `.rangeClosed` method is inclusive, filling the array to 100 elements `int[] a = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).toArray();` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html

Comment: Minimum API level is 24? 

Answer (score 23):

Another alternative if you use Java 8:

```
int[] array = new int[100];
Arrays.setAll(array, i -> i + 1);
```

The lambda expression accepts the index of the cell, and returns a value to put in that cell. In this case, cells 0 - 99 are assigned the values 1-100.

Comment: How is the performance of this compared to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 19):

Java 8 allows to do that in one line with `IntStream` object and lambda expression:

```
int n = 10;
int[] values = new int[n];
IntStream.range(1,n+1).forEach(val -> values[val-1] = val);
```

Comment: Arrays.setAll() is a much better way

Answer (score 2):

I think that your code is the **shortest** and the **simplest** way. You might dont need to load extra libraries to get more "compact" code lines. The **for** loops are very simple (a truly O(n)) and **legible**, live and love them.

Answer (score 1):

depending on the size you will have to loop, if its a small one you can do the following...

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {4,5,6,7,8};
```

im guessing for your size you dont want to have to type it all out so makes sense to create a loop and set it that way

Answer (score 1):

If people **do** want to use the for-loop method, then you could shorten it to (side note):

```
int [] a = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; a[i] = i++);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava library, for something like this:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //one liner
    int[] array = toArray(newLinkedList(concat(range(1, 10), range(500, 1000))));

    //more readable
    Iterable<Integer> values = concat(range(1, 10), range(500, 1000));
    List<Integer> list = newLinkedList(values);
    int[] array = toArray(list);

}

public static List<Integer> range(int min, int max) {
    List<Integer> list = newLinkedList();
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    return list;
}
```

}

**Updated**: full example take from this post [Fill arrays with ranges of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387373/fill-arrays-with-ranges-of-numbers)

Comment: the `range` method is not part of guava and has been written using a loop in that answer. It does not help here.

Comment: Probably you are right, i remember that ot was something like this, but took example from linked post as is

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is not able to use java 8+, here is a solution with Google Guava:

```
Long[] value = ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(0L, 23L), DiscreteDomain.longs())
.toArray(new Long[0]);
```

Answer (score -2):

You must use loop to initialize such a long array. There is not a shortcut method in Java as you expected.