# How do I convert a Java 8 IntStream to a List?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm looking at the docs for the `IntStream`, and I see an `toArray` method, but no way to go directly to a `List<Integer>`

Surely there is a way to convert a `Stream` to a `List`?

Comment: Try this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830313/retrieving-a-list-from-a-java-util-stream-stream-in-java8

Comment: @KarlRichter The other question doesn't give you a typed list. Also, this question was from four years ago, and has an answer with 300+ upvotes. Why are we trying to merge it now?

Answer (score 750, accepted):

## `IntStream::boxed`

[`IntStream::boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) turns an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) into a [`Stream<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html), which you can then [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) into a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html):

```
theIntStream.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The `boxed` method converts the `int` primitive values of an `IntStream` into a stream of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) objects. The word ["boxing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing) names the `int` ⬌ `Integer` conversion process. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

### Java 16 and later

Java 16 brought the shorter [`toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) method. Produces an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable). Discussed [here](https://todd.ginsberg.com/post/java-16/stream-tolist/).

```
theIntStream.boxed().toList()
```

Comment: @skiwi I mean, that all the other answers are unneeded after this one as they would be not so natural.

Comment: Thank you I hadn't seen the boxed method yet and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Addition: I think this codes gets a little shorter, clearer and prettier if you use a static import of `toList`. This is done by placing the following among the imports of the file: `static import java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;`. Then the collect call reads just `.collect(toList())`.

Comment: In Eclipse it is possible to make the IDE add a static import for methods. This is done by adding the `Collectors` class in *Preferences* -> *Java* -> *Editor* -> *Content Assist* -> *Favorites*. After this, you only have to type `toLi` at hit *Ctr+Space* to have the IDE fill in `toList` and add the static import.

Comment: Was tearing my hair out about what was wrong with what I had tried, thank you for pointing out the `boxed()` part

Comment: Don't forget to `import java.util.stream.Collectors;`.

Comment: I was happy to get this answer -- and more broadly, these features in Java 8.

Looking back after two years working in Python, and I'm so glad I don't have to deal with this nonsense.

Comment: java stream api is un-straightforward at so many levels..

Answer (score 25):

You could also use mapToObj() on a Stream, which takes an IntFunction and returns an object-valued Stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

```
List<Integer> intList = myIntStream.mapToObj(i->i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: In a stroke of irony, this is what `boxed()` is delegating to.

Answer (score 9):

You can use primitive collections available in [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) and avoid boxing.

```
MutableIntList list = 
    IntStream.range(1, 5)
    .collect(IntArrayList::new, MutableIntList::add, MutableIntList::addAll);
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.

Comment: Although Eclipse Collections are usually quite helpful, this does not look like it is making anything easier at all :)

Comment: Since EC 9.0, you can build a primitive list from a primitive Stream.  `MutableIntList list = IntLists.mutable.withAll(IntStream.range(1, 5))`

Comment: This is what I was looking for .. boxing the int stream to Integer or to object is different thing

Answer (score 8):

You can use the collect method:

```
IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll);
```

In fact, this is almost exactly what Java is doing when you call .collect(Collectors.toList()) on an object stream:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
    return new Collectors.CollectorImpl(ArrayList::new, List::add, (var0, var1) -> {
        var0.addAll(var1);
        return var0;
    }, CH_ID);
}
```

Note: The third parameter is only required if you want to run parallel collection; for sequential collection providing just the first two will suffice.

Comment: That last sentence explains it all.

Answer (score 3):

Find the folowing example of finding square of each int element using Java 8 :-

```
IntStream ints = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5});       
List<Integer> intsList = ints.map(x-> x*x)
          .collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```