# Converting String of digits to List of integer

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am doing some hands on exercise on java 8 stream features so thought of applying the knowledge with the problem **Converting String of digits to List of integer**

a typical test would look like

```
 @Test
    public void testGetListofIntegersFromString(){
        List<Integer> result = getIntegers("123456780");
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0),result);
    }
```

I have written below method

```
List<Integer> getIntegers(String value) {
       return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, value.length() - 1).map(i -> Integer.valueOf(value.substring(i,i+1))).collect(?????);
    }
```

I am stuck about which function to use to get The List Of Integers 
I tried `collect(Collectors.toList())` Its giving compilation error.

Please suggest if we can follow different to solve this .

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: I am getting an like Error:(61, 109) java: method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
  required: `java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>`
  found: `java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>`
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Have you tried using [`mapToInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) instead of `map`?

Comment: `mapToInt` method is not available in `IntStream` , Should I use the class `Stream` ?

Comment: My mistake, I see the issue now; your stream is of `int` which cannot be used as a type parameter for list (you need `Integer`). This question thus boils down to the question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23674624/1247781). Using `boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())` should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use String.chars():

```
"123456780".chars().map(c -> c-'0').boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: why do not use this: c -> c - 48.

Comment: @Win.ubuntu, because `'0'` is less obscure to the reader. I personally know many ASCII codes in both decimal and hexadecimal, but I guess no more than 10% of programmers can readily answer "what symbol corresponds to ASCII code 48".

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: Right, even if we know the codepoints, `48` offers no advantage over `'0'`. And *if* we really have to show off in the code, we use `c -> c&017` anyway…

Comment: You may also consider `"123456780".chars().mapToObj(Character::getNumericValue).collect(Collectors.toList());`