# How can I sort an IntStream in ascending order?

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

I've converted a 2D int array into a Stream:

```
IntStream dataStream = Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToInt(x -> Arrays.stream(x));
```

Now, I want to sort the list into ascending order. I've tried this:

```
dataStream.sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but I get the compile time error
[image: error]

I'm confused about this, because on the examples I've seen, similar things are done without errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with

```
dataStream.sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

because `collect(Collectors.toList())` does not apply to a `IntStream`.

I also think that should be slightly better for performance call first `sorted()` and then `boxed()`.

`IntStream.collect()` method has the following signature:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

If you really want use this you could:

```
.collect(IntArrayList::new, MutableIntList::add, MutableIntList::addAll);
```

As suggested here:

[How do I convert a Java 8 IntStream to a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674624/how-do-i-convert-a-java-8-intstream-to-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to convert an `int` stream to a list, but `Collectors.toList` only works on streams of objects, not streams of primitives.

You'll need to box the array before collecting it into the list:

`dataStream.sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`