# How to convert Stream<int[]> to Stream<Integer>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way convert `Stream<int[]>` to `Stream<Integer>`

```
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 54, 432, 53, 21, 43 };
// Below gives me Stream<int[]> 

Stream.of(arr2);  // I want to convert it to Stream<Integer>
```

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a Java 8 IntStream to a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674624/how-do-i-convert-a-java-8-intstream-to-a-list) and/or [How to convert int array to Integer array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

You can use either `Arrays.stream()`

```
Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed();  // will return Stream<Integer>
```

Or `IntStream.of`

```
IntStream.of(arr2).boxed();   // will return Stream<Integer>
```

**Stream**<**Integer**> **boxed()**

> Returns a Stream consisting of the elements of this stream, each boxed to an Integer.
>
> This is an intermediate operation.

Answer (score 4):

box the stream:

```
Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed();
```

Comment: @AshishkumarSingh If you **really** insisted on starting with `Stream.of(arr2)` then you could do `Stream.of(arr2).flatMap(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).boxed())`. But I don't know why you'd want to.

Comment: @Michael or `Stream.of(arr2).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).boxed()`

Comment: @Holger I was looking for what you commented. I know it doesn't make much sense to use when we have `Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed()`, but I just wanted to learn how can I achieve it if we have `Stream<int[]>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
Integer[] arr = Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: There is no method `boxed` for `arr2`

Answer (score 1):

You can create Stream from [io.vavr](http://www.vavr.io/) with

```
Stream.ofAll(arr2)
```

but you want to use stream of integers you should use IntStream. You can create IntStream from array like this:

```
Arrays.stream(arr2)
```

Comment: Oh i've used Stream class from io.vavr

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in this case.

Let's look at an example. If you have an array of primitives and try to create a stream directly you will have a stream of one array object, like this:

```
// Arrays of primitives 
int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
Stream.of(nums); // One element int[] | Stream<int[]>
```

To solve this you can use:

```
Arrays.stream(nums).count();  // Five Elements 
IntStream.of(nums).count(); // Five Elements
```