# Java stream - map and store array of int into Set

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have an array of `[5, 6, 7, 3, 9]`, I would like to change each element from the array substracting by 2, then store the in a `Set`, so what I did is

```
Set<Integer> mySet = Arrays.stream(arr1).map(ele -> new Integer(ele - 2)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

but I am getting two exceptions here as

1. `The method collect(Supplier<R>, ObjIntConsumer<R>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Object,?,Set<Object>>)`"
2. `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Object,capture#1-of ?,Set<Object>> to Supplier<R>`

What does those error mean and how can I fix the issue here with `Java Stream` operation?

Comment: Dont use `new Integer(...)`, it is deprecated for good reason. Use `Integer.valueOf(...)` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Zabuzard, that was a nice hint!

Comment: Closely related if not duplicate - [How do I convert a Java 8 IntStream to a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674624/how-do-i-convert-a-java-8-intstream-to-a-list)

Comment: @Naman *Very* closely related, but I am not sure if it is a duplicate, because OP doesn't seem to have known that they were working with an `IntStream`

Comment: @Lino at least the error message reads that explicitly, just some debugging efforts away if I could say so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like `arr1` is an `int[]` and therefore, `Arrays.stream(arr1)` returns an `IntStream`. You can't apply `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` on an `IntStream`.

You can box it to a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
Set<Integer> mySet = Arrays.stream(arr1)
                           .boxed()
                           .map(ele -> ele - 2)
                           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or even simpler:

```
Set<Integer> mySet = Arrays.stream(arr1)
                           .mapToObj(ele -> ele - 2)
                           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: yes, you're right, the arr1 is an int[], so does it mean `.boxed().map(ele -> ele - 2)` and `.mapToObj(ele -> ele - 2)` both returns an IntStream? and is `boxed()` only could be applied on `IntStream` to convert into an `Stream<Integer>`?

Comment: No, they both return a `Stream<Integer>`. They are applied on `IntStream`. And yes, `boxed()` converts an `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`.

Answer (score 7):

`Arrays.stream(int[])` returns an `IntStream`. And `IntStream` does not offer `collect()` methods that take a `Collector`.

If you need to use `Collectors.toSet()`, then you need a `Stream<Integer>` for it, and you can call `mapToObj` for that:

```
Set<Integer> mySet = Arrays.stream(arr1)
                           .mapToObj(ele -> ele - 2)
                           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a third-party library, you can avoid boxing the `int` values as `Integer` using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) `IntSet`.

```
int[] array = {5, 6, 7, 3, 9};
IntStream stream = Arrays.stream(array).map(value -> value - 2);
IntSet actual = IntSets.mutable.ofAll(stream);
IntSet expected = IntSets.mutable.of(3, 4, 5, 1, 7);
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.