# Why elements are added incorrectly in List<int[]> in Java?

Tags: java

On my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540279/how-to-replace-recursion-in-my-code-on-java) user `@deadshot` give me answer.

I decided to little change the program.
I add one object - `ArrayList<int[]> combinations`, which will store `array int[]` with numbers (size this array is always 3).
I add to `combinations` arrays (`array[]`) using the method `add()`.

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static int POINTS_ON_LINE = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] points = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};

        System.out.println("no repetitions:");
        p1(points, POINTS_ON_LINE);
    }

    public static void p1(int[] arr, int pointsOnLine) {
        List<int[]> combinations = new ArrayList<>();

        int lengthArray = arr.length, i;
        int[] index = new int[pointsOnLine];
        int[] temp = new int[pointsOnLine];

        for (i = 0; i < pointsOnLine; i++) {
            index[i] = i;
        }

        if (pointsOnLine < lengthArray) {
            for (int j : index) {
                temp[j] = arr[j];
            }

            boolean flag;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Add array: " + Arrays.toString(temp));
                combinations.add(temp);

                flag = false;

                for (i = pointsOnLine - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (index[i] != i + lengthArray - pointsOnLine) {
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!flag) {
                    break;
                }

                index[i] += 1;

                for (int j = i + 1; j < pointsOnLine; j++) {
                    index[j] = index[j - 1] + 1;
                }

                for (i = 0; i < pointsOnLine; i++) {
                    temp[i] = arr[index[i]];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("End");
        }
        System.out.println("Result");
        for(int[] q : combinations) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(q));
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the result like this:

```
no repetitions:
Add array: [1, 2, 3]
Add array: [1, 2, 4]
Add array: [1, 3, 4]
Add array: [2, 3, 4]
End

Result:
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Why object `combinations` contain:

```
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
```

But object `combinations` should be contain this:

```
[1, 2, 3]  
[1, 2, 4]  
[1, 3, 4]  
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: It happens because you modify `temp`.

Comment: @Nikolas, `ArrayList<int[]>` doesn't store `HIS COPY` of the array?

Comment: @Progman, yes, it looks like this. So, what I must do, so that the values don't change?

Comment: @n199a You can create a copy of the array you want to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
combinations.add(temp);
```

To this:

```
combinations.add(Arrays.stream(temp).toArray());
```

This will get a copy of the array at it's current state, and add it to the List. This is using the stream api from java 8.

Comment: I did so ```java
combinations.add(Arrays.copyOf(temp, temp.length));
```. But, thank you.