# How to convert IntStream to List in java?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I would like to convert Stream of random numbers to list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
                new Random().ints(10, 0, 20).
                        collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

But that gives an exception

```
java: method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>
  found: java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

so how can I convert stream to list in java?

Comment: The `ints()` method returns an `IntStream`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674624/how-do-i-convert-a-java-8-intstream-to-a-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a Java 8 IntStream to a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674624/how-do-i-convert-a-java-8-intstream-to-a-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Explanation

[`Random#ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#ints(long,int,int)) returns `IntStream`, not a `Stream<Integer>`, that is the problem.

`IntStream` is a special class to represent primitive `int`s. But generics in Java do not support primitives, i.e. there is no `List<int>`. So you first have to make your `int`s `Integer`s, the wrapper class. Then you can collect to `List<Integer>`.

---

### Solution

Just **box** it and it works.

```
stream.boxed().toList() // since Java 16
// or
stream.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Also see the documentation of [`IntStream#boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()):

> Returns a Stream consisting of the elements of this stream, each boxed to an Integer.

For understanding, `boxed()` is roughly equivalent to

```
stream.mapToObj(x -> Integer.valueOf(x))
```

---

So in your case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
        new Random()
            .ints(10, 0, 20)
            .boxed()
            .toList());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `List` cannot contain primitives, so you need to use a wrapper type such as `Integer`. To achieve this, call `boxed()` (which converts your `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`) prior to calling `collect()`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
                new Random().ints(10, 0, 20).boxed().
                        collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: (note that `Stream#toList()` is a thing, since Java 16)

Comment: Good to know, though I generally base my answers on the LTS version of Java, which would be 11

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `boxed` in order to get `Stream<Integer>` from `IntStream` and access the desired `collect` overloaded method:

```
new Random().ints(10, 0, 20)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: (note that `Stream#toList()` is a thing, since Java 16)

Answer (score 2):

**Just use .boxed() in your IntStream reference.**

for eg:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Java8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream ints = new Random().ints(10, 0, 20); //here ints is your intstream
        List<Integer> collect = ints.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()); 
/*
  Here Just use ints.boxed() and then collect to list 
*/
        collect.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```