# short, clever way to create InputStream from byte sequence

Tags: java, arrays, byte, sequence, java-stream

I want an `InputStream` to a sequence of bytes: `0`, `1`, `2`, ... `255`.

I can of course create a `new byte[0x100]`, create a loop of `int`, fill it with the `int` values cast to `byte` (don't get me started on Java's signed `byte` type), and then form a `ByteArrayInputStream` from that.

But surely with Java 8 there is a better, more compact, and cleverer way. The trick seems to be generating the array of bytes. I found [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30020546/421049) that with `int` it's as easy as the following:

```
final int[] values =  IntStream.range(0, 0x100).toArray();
```

But I need a `byte` array, and there is no `ByteStream`. Perhaps there is an `IntStream` collection function that could collect the `int` values into a `byte[]` array? Or something even cleverer?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're starting from an InputStream or a byte sequence? Your question suggests both. And what form does the source or desired byte sequence take? E.g., is it a byte[], or a Stream<Byte>, or something else?

Comment: An `InputStream` that produces a particular sequence is where I want to _end_, not start. A `byte[]` seems an obvious means, but feel free to skip the byte array if you have a more direct trick for creating an `InputStream`.

Comment: What form does your byte sequence take? Is it the specific sequence {1,2,...,255}? Or is it some type of container of arbitrary bytes?

Comment: Let's go with `0` – `255` for the sake of argument.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the `byte[]` and then use an `IntStream` with a `forEach` to fill it. Something like

```
byte[] arr = new byte[256];
IntStream.range(0, arr.length).forEach(x -> arr[x] = (byte) x);
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop would be faster, but if you are asking for the sake of discussion how you might solve it with streams, you could do this, with a little help from the guava `Bytes` api:

```
byte[] bytes = IntStream.range(0, 0x100)
    .mapToObj(i -> (byte) i)                        // boxes into a Byte
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Bytes::toArray))
```

In this example, each int is wrapped in a Byte, which are collected to a List and then converted to a byte[].

The advantage of this approach is that it works without knowing the size of the destination array in advance.  If you know the size of the array, @ElliotFrisch's answer would be more efficient, and a loop more efficient still.

Answer (score 0):

It's too bad that there isn't a byte version of `Arrays.setAll`.  It would have worked like this:

```
byte[] foo = new byte[0x100];
setAll(foo, i -> i++);
```

If someone really wanted it though, they could use this, adapted from the `int` version of `Arrays.setAll`:

```
public static void setAll(byte[] array, IntUnaryOperator generator) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(generator);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = (byte)generator.applyAsInt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create lazy `InputStream` from an `IntStream` (using least significant bytes only), you may try this:

```
public static InputStream asByteInputStream(IntStream is) {
    Spliterator.OfInt spltr = is.spliterator();
    return new InputStream() {
        private int last;

        @Override
        public int read() {
            return spltr.tryAdvance((int val) -> last = val) ? (last & 0xFF) : -1;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            is.close();
        }
    };
}
```

Usage tests:

```
AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
InputStream is = asByteInputStream(IntStream.range(0, 256).onClose(() -> flag.set(true)));
byte[] data = new byte[256];
assertEquals(2, is.skip(2));
// read 3..255 into data[0..253]
assertEquals(254, is.read(data));
// nothing more in the input
assertEquals(-1, is.read());
for(int i=0; i<254; i++) {
    assertEquals((byte)(i+2), data[i]);
}
assertEquals(0, data[254]);
assertEquals(0, data[255]);

// close is forwarded to original IntStream
assertFalse(flag.get());
is.close();
assertTrue(flag.get());
```