# How to improve an algorithm to get pairs of numbers which multiplied are equal to the sum of a range of numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, function, loops, sum

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Is my friend cheating?](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5547cc7dcad755e480000004). The statement is:

> A friend of mine takes a sequence of numbers from 1 to n (where n >
>   0).
>       Within that sequence, he chooses two numbers, a and b.
>       He says that the product of a and b should be equal to the sum of all numbers in the sequence, excluding a and b.
>       Given a number n, could you tell me the numbers he excluded from the sequence?
>
> The function takes the parameter: n (n is always strictly greater than
>   0) and returns an array or a string (depending on the language) of the
>   form:
>
> [(a, b), ...] or [[a, b], ...] or {{a, b}, ...} or or [{a, b}, ...]
>
> with all (a, b) which are the possible removed numbers in the sequence
>   1 to n.
>
> [(a, b), ...] or [[a, b], ...] or {{a, b}, ...} or ...will be sorted
>   in increasing order of the "a".
>
> It happens that there are several possible (a, b). The function
>   returns an empty array (or an empty string) if no possible numbers are
>   found which will prove that my friend has not told the truth! (Go: in
>   this case return nil).
>
> Examples:
>
> removeNb(26) should return [[15, 21], [21, 15]]

The idea was:

```
Calculate sum of 1..n
For each number a
 For each number b
  if a*b=sum-(a+b)
   add to result
```

And I have written the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class RemovedNumbers {
    public static List<long[]> removNb(long n) {
    System.out.println("n: "+n);
    long sum = LongStream.rangeClosed(1,n).sum();
    List<long[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("sum: "+sum);
    for(int a = 1; a <= n && a <= sum; a++){
      System.out.println("a: "+a);
      long prodMax = a*n;
      long sumMax = sum-(a+n);
      if(prodMax < sumMax){
        System.out.println("prodMax: "+prodMax);
        System.out.println("sumMax: "+sumMax);
        continue;
      };
      for(int b = 1; b <= n && a*b <= (sum-(a+b)); b++){
        if(a==b) continue;
        System.out.println("b: "+b);
        if(a*b == sum-(a+b)){
          result.add(new long[]{a,b});
          System.out.println("result: "+Arrays.deepToString(result.toArray()));
        }    
      }
    }
    System.out.println("result: "+Arrays.deepToString(result.toArray()));
    return result;
    }
}
```

It passes the following tests:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RemovedNumbersTest {
  @Test
    public void test12() {
        List<long[]> res = new ArrayList<long[]>();
        res.add(new long[] {15, 21});
        res.add(new long[] {21, 15});
        List<long[]> a = RemovedNumbers.removNb(26);
        assertArrayEquals(res.get(0), a.get(0));
        assertArrayEquals(res.get(1), a.get(1));
    }
    @Test
    public void test14() {
        List<long[]> res = new ArrayList<long[]>();
        List<long[]> a = RemovedNumbers.removNb(100);
        assertTrue(res.size() == a.size());
    }
}
```

For example for test12, the trace is:

```
n: 26
sum: 351
a: 1
prodMax: 26
sumMax: 324
a: 2
prodMax: 52
sumMax: 323
a: 3
prodMax: 78
sumMax: 322
a: 4
prodMax: 104
sumMax: 321
a: 5
prodMax: 130
sumMax: 320
a: 6
prodMax: 156
sumMax: 319
a: 7
prodMax: 182
sumMax: 318
a: 8
prodMax: 208
sumMax: 317
a: 9
prodMax: 234
sumMax: 316
a: 10
prodMax: 260
sumMax: 315
a: 11
prodMax: 286
sumMax: 314
a: 12
prodMax: 312
sumMax: 313
a: 13
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 14
b: 15
b: 16
b: 17
b: 18
b: 19
b: 20
b: 21
b: 22
b: 23
b: 24
a: 14
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
b: 15
b: 16
b: 17
b: 18
b: 19
b: 20
b: 21
b: 22
a: 15
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
b: 14
b: 16
b: 17
b: 18
b: 19
b: 20
b: 21
result: [[15, 21]]
a: 16
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
b: 14
b: 15
b: 17
b: 18
b: 19
a: 17
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
b: 14
b: 15
b: 16
b: 18
a: 18
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
b: 14
b: 15
b: 16
b: 17
a: 19
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
b: 14
b: 15
b: 16
a: 20
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
b: 14
b: 15
a: 21
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
b: 14
b: 15
result: [[15, 21], [21, 15]]
a: 22
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
b: 14
a: 23
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
a: 24
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
b: 13
a: 25
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
a: 26
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
b: 10
b: 11
b: 12
result: [[15, 21], [21, 15]]
```

However when the input is a big number, for example n=1000003, it times out (execution time is bigger than 16000ms).

I have also read:

- [Fill arrays with ranges of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387373/fill-arrays-with-ranges-of-numbers)
- [How to sum a list of integers with java streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125296/how-to-sum-a-list-of-integers-with-java-streams)

How could we improve this algorithm?

Comment: You can compute the sum of the integers from 1 to n directly as n*(n+1)/2. This is a standard homework exercise in first term algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate through the second number in your pair. You can iterate only through the first number of pair and calculate the second one. If `x` is the first number (you iterate through it), `y` is the second number (you want to find it) and `s` is the sum of all numbers then you just need to solve this equation:

```
x * y = s - x - y    <=>

(x + 1) * y = s - x    <=>

y = (s - x) / (x + 1)
```

So if `(s - x) / (x + 1)` is integer and is not equal to `x`, it's the second number in pair.

With this change your algorithm will work in O(n), not in O(n^2).